# showDialog in initState after invokeMethod from java code

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, flutter-state, flutter-android

I want to show a dialog in whole app when a intent is triggered.
For this, I add onNewIntent listener in android and invoke a flutter method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED")) {
        methodChannel.invokeMethod("method_name", null);
    }
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

and in the main.dart, in initState method set a methodCallHandler for this method:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AndroidApi.platform.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
      debugPrint("here");
      if (call.method == "method_name") {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => const LoadingDialog(),
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

In the console, I see the onNewIntent log and `"method_name"` is called. and I see the `"here"` log in my console. but the dialog is not shown. Can you find the problem?

Comment: try `debugPrint(call.method)` or make a debugPrint inside the if, to at least confirm it gets inside the if

Comment: @Ivo I tried this. It gets inside the if.

Comment: It can be related to the `context` you pass to `showDialog`. By the time `showDialog` gets called, the current context my be different from what you passed in `initState`. You could try to use `await` before `showDialog` to wait for the future to complete.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I tried this. But still not working ...

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 if (call.method == "method_name") {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => const LoadingDialog(),
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: still not working ...